# Country not listed Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

On https://climb-europe.com I don't have Denmark listed in the country dropdown at checkout NOR in the list of allowed countries in the backend
In the directory_country table is listed as country_id DK, iso2 DK and ISO 3 DNK
It is also listed in en.xml - Denmark
The locale for the store is UK so en_gb and it has multi stores

Anyone have any ideas as to how to get Denmark showing up in the lsit of countries

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow this steps.**

```
Step1: Open lib/zend/locale/data/en.xml

Step2: Locate territories tag in this file

Step3: copy one of territory tags for the syntax and paste it within the territories tag

Step4: hard part here is to add country code in this file as might not be able to find a unique one, so it’s upto you.

Step5: Save this file

Step6: Open table name directory_country

Step7: It has predefined syntax follow then same and create a new row and enter the same country code as entered in the en.xml file in 3 columns

Step8: Refresh the site’s cache.

Step9: Admin > Configuration > General
```

Thanks